# Oscillations with paralleled MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, oscillation

I m actually reading a section of a book which talks about parralleling MOSFETs. The book talk about "Power supply design". There is a sub section which describes how to design the circuit layout. It finally say : "Finally, to prevent oscillations with paralleled MOSFETs, resistors of 10 to 20  Ohm or ferrite beads should be placed in series with gate leads".

I'm surprised ! I have never seen a power MOSFET oscillates... And I actually do not understand what it means by oscillations. In which case oscillations happens ? And why when we parallelise MOSFET we increase the risk of seeing oscillatons ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=59458 check this out

Comment: "Oscillates" means it rings when switching, so underdamped. If you scope the gate-source voltage you can see it. This can happen with single MOSFETs too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power MOSFETs have relatively large Gate-Drain capacitances.

When they are paralleled, you have a closed AC loop from common Gate to Drain1 to Drain2 back to common Gate.

What do you need for oscillation? 1) An energy source [check] 2) feedback [check]

So it’s good to insert a resistor for each gate for damping purposes.